# Can BFS be used to identify the furthest vertex?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Can we use BFS algo to identify the furthest vertex from staring vertex v in any graph, in terms of number of edges.

Comment: If the graph has no cycles, easily. If it has cycles and you're looking for the longest cycle-free path, the problem is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let's call the distance from A node to B node the number of edges from A to B. 
BFS is finding all the nodes of distance 1, then all nodes of distance 2 and so on. For finding the furthest vertex just retain the last node searched, because he has certain the longest distance.

Comment: But what if the graph has a cycle?

Comment: @rici It doesn't even matter if graph has cycle. BFS is searching for closing points always.

Comment: If by "closing points" you mean "leaves", then it's not going to work because the graph might not have any leaves. Suppose your algorithm worked for any graph. Then I could use it to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem, since the TSP is clearly the longest non-cyclic path. But the TSP is well-known to be NP-Hard. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @rici - there is a difference between finding the longest path in a graph (which is a hard problem) to finding the vertex with the longest shortest path of all vertices.

Comment: @shahara: absolutely. So one needs to clarify what is being sought.